# Seam centralized exceptions

Tags: java, exception, seam

i'm using seam 2.2, primefaces as view presentation layer.
I would write some kind of infrastructure in order to capture all exceptions.
For example i put in a facelets following piece of code:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mySeamController.aMethod()}"
```

in MySeamController class, the above method:

```
public void aMethod()
{
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

in the controller i write a method:

```
 @Observer("myapp.exceptions.exception")
 public void onSystemException(Exception e)
 {  
  System.out.println("a exception was occurred");

 }
```

i write a class to catch exceptions:

```
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@BypassInterceptors
@Install( precedence = Install.MOCK, classDependencies = "javax.faces.context.FacesContext")
@Name("org.jboss.seam.exception.exceptions")
public class ExceptionHandler extends org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions{


 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Logger
    Log log;

 public void handle(Exception e) throws Exception 
 {            
  Events.instance().raiseEvent("myapp.exceptions.exception", e);
  super.handle(e);

 }
}
```

but i've noticed taht when i use an actionListener

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mySeamController.aMethod()}"
```

instead of an action

```
<p:commandButton action="#{mySeamController.aMethod()}"
```

no exception was observed by ExceptionHandler class.
Why? Can anyone help?
Best regards

Comment: Did you ever solve this? This isn't a solution, but to save yourself some trouble, take a look at the Exceptions class source code. It raises events for the exceptions throw, so you don't have to create an intermediate handler: Events.instance().raiseEvent("org.jboss.seam.exceptionNotHandled", e); Events.instance().raiseEvent("org.jboss.seam.exceptionHandled", cause); I use this to track user session exceptions (at least Seam exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Create an interceptor, and you will can catch anything you need.